# Why I should use context.become() to store internal state in Actor?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I've read [scala-best-practices](https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/5-actors.md) and have a question about "5.2. SHOULD mutate state in actors only with context.become". I don't understand why it is so bad to store internal state using `var`. If actor executes all messages sequentially I just can't see any source of problems. What do I miss?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the first example in the [article](https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/5-actors.md#52-should-mutate-state-in-actors-only-with-contextbecome) that you referenced:

```
class MyActor extends Actor {
  val isInSet = mutable.Set.empty[String]

  def receive = {
    case Add(key) =>
      isInSet += key

    case Contains(key) =>
      sender() ! isInSet(key)
  }
}
```

There's nothing inherently incorrect with this example, so there isn't some vital understanding that you're missing. As you know, an actor processes the messages in its mailbox sequentially, so it *is* safe to represent its state in an internal variable and to mutate this state, *as long as the actor doesn't expose that state*<sup>1</sup>.

`become` is often used to dynamically switch an actor's behavior (e.g., changing the kind of messages that the actor handles) and/or its state. In the second example in the article, the actor's state is encoded in its behavior as a parameter. This is an elegant alternative to the first example, but in this simple case it's a matter of preference.

One scenario in which `become` can really shine, however, is an actor that has many state transitions. Without the use of `become`, the actor's logic in its `receive` block can grow unmanageably large or turn into a jungle of `if-else` statements. As an example of using `become` to model state transitions, check out this [sample project](https://github.com/akka/akka-samples/blob/2.5/akka-sample-fsm-scala/src/main/scala/sample/become/DiningHakkersOnBecome.scala) that models the ["Dining Philosophers"](http://www.dalnefre.com/wp/2010/08/dining-philosophers-in-humus/) problem.

---

<sup>1</sup>A potential issue is that while `isInSet` is a `val`, it's a mutable `Set`, so weird things can happen if the actor exposes this state to something outside of the actor itself (which it is not doing in the example). For example, if the actor sends this `Set` in a message to another actor, then the external actor can change this state, causing unexpected behavior or race conditions. One can mitigate this issue by changing the `val` to a `var`, and the mutable Set to an immutable `Set`.

Comment: I started studying scala and this answer is not just the most concise but the fullest +1

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's necessarily anything wrong with using `var`s in actors, for exactly the reasons you mentioned (Keep in mind though, that this is only for code executed in the context of the `receive(...)`, i.e., if you start a thread, or use a `Future`, even if it's from within the `receive`, that code is no longer executed sequentially).

However, I personally prefer to use `context.become(...)` for controlling state, mainly because it clearly shows me the states in the actor that can change (`var`s can be scattered all over).

I also prefer to limit it to 0 or 1 call to `context.become(...)` per message handled, so it's clear where this state transition is happening.

That said, you can get the same benefits by using a convention where you define all your `var`s in one place, and make sure to re-assign them in one place (say towards the end) in your message handling.

Comment: What do you mean by "even if it's from the receive"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "even if it's from _within_ the receive". What I meant is, if inside your receive function, if you were to do something like `Future { someMutableNumber += 1 }`, `someMutableNumber` will no longer be accessed sequentially, and will be subject to race conditions.