# Sample most recent element of Akka Stream with trigger signal, using zipWith?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I have a `Planning` system that computes kind of a global `Schedule` from customer orders.  This schedule changes over time when customers place or revoke orders to this system, or when certain resources used by events within the schedule become unavailable.

Now another system needs to know the status of certain events in the `Schedule`.  The system sends a `StatusRequest(EventName)` on a message queue to which I must react with a corresponding `StatusSignal(EventStatus)` on another queue.

The `Planning` system gives me an akka-streams `Source[Schedule]` which emits a `Schedule` whenever the schedule changed, and I also have a `Source[StatusRequest]` from which I receive `StatusRequest`s and a `Sink[StatusSignal]` to which I can send `StatusSignal` responses.

**Whenever I receive a `StatusRequest` I must inspect the current schedule, ie, the most recent value emitted by `Source[Schedule]`, and send a `StatusSignal` to the sink.**

I came up with the following flow

```
scheduleSource
  .zipWith(statusRequestSource) { (schedule, statusRequest) => 
    findEventStatus(schedule, statusRequest.eventName))
  }
  .map(eventStatus => makeStatusSignal(eventStatus))
  .runWith(statusSignalSink)
```

but I am not at all sure when this flow actually emits values and whether it actually implements my requirement (see bold text above).

The [zipWith reference](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/zipWith.html) says (emphasis mine):

> emits when **all** of the inputs have an element available

What does this mean?  When `statusRequestSource` emits a value does the flow wait until `scheduleSource` emits, too?  Or does it use the last value `scheduleSource` emitted?  Likewise, what happens when `scheduleSource` emits a value?  Does it trigger a status signal with the last element in `statusRequestSource`?

If the flow doesn't implement what I need, how could I achieve it instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first set of questions regarding the behavior of `zipWith`, here is a simple test:

```
val source1 = Source(1 to 5)
val source2 = Source(1 to 3)

source1
  .zipWith(source2){ (s1Elem, s2Elem) => (s1Elem, s2Elem) }
  .runForeach(println)

// prints:
// (1,1)
// (2,2)
// (3,3)
```

`zipWith` will emit downstream as long as both inputs have respective elements that can be zipped together.

One idea to fulfill your requirement is to decouple `scheduleSource` and `statusRequestSource`. Feed `scheduleSource` to an actor, and have the actor track the most recent element it has received from the stream. Then have `statusRequestSource` [query this actor](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-integrations.html#integrating-with-actors), which will reply with the most recent element from `scheduleSource`. This actor could look something like the following:

```
class LatestElementTracker extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  var latestSchedule: Option[Schedule] = None

  def receive = {
    case schedule: Schedule =>
      latestSchedule = Some(schedule)
    case status: StatusRequest =>
      if (latestSchedule.isEmpty) {
        log.debug("No schedules have been received yet.")
      } else {
        val eventStatus = findEventStatus(latestSchedule.get, status.eventName)
        sender() ! eventStatus
      }
  }
}
```

To integrate with the above actor:

```
scheduleSource.runForeach(s => trackerActor ! s)

statusRequestSource
  .ask[EventStatus](parallelism = 1)(trackerActor) // adjust parallelism as needed
  .map(eventStatus => makeStatusSignal(eventStatus))
  .runWith(statusSignalSink)
```

Comment: Thank you very much; I'll try this one.  I also had the idea to just keep an explicit reference to the last element, but I had hoped that akka-streams provides something like this out of the box—it just seemed to be a common problem.

Comment: I finally got to work on this again, and looking at your example again, I realized that you use a mutable `var` in the tracker actor.  Out of curiosity, why did you not use `become`?  I thought one should avoid mutable state in actors.

Comment: @lunaryorn In this case, using a `var` instead of `become` is a matter of preference. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47600540/865401) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the reference to the answer.